# ionic 5 Angular VSCode unbound breakpoint

Tags: angular, debugging, ionic-framework, visual-studio-code, breakpoints

I have an Ionic 5 Angular 12 app recently migrated from Ionic 4 Angular 8.
The app runs well and is stable, but I have broken behaviours for debugging.

- First, if I use VS Code launch.json file to run, it deploys well but immediatly dettach in VS Code with only a standard error popup saying "" with no logs at all in console or logcat. [image]But then I can attach back easily with "Attach on android device".
- Second, every breakpoints I set is marked as "Unbound Breakpoint" as soon as I attach app and never fires. But setting a "debugger;" in code works.
- Third, live reload does'nt work netiher but I assume both are related.

I tried with a starting Ionic 5 project and it works in my environment (VS Code, Cordova Tools...), so the problem comes from my app, probably packages but can't find out why.

VS Code 1.63.2
Cordova Tools 2.4.0
My Ionic Info :
[image]

Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "anonym",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "https://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "apk:build": "ionic cordova build --release android",
    "apk:align": "zipalign.exe -f -v 4 ./platforms/android/app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release-unsigned.apk ../APK/%npm_package_name%%npm_package_config_prefix%.%npm_package_version%.apk",
    "apk:sign": "apksigner sign --verbose --ks %npm_package_config_keystorepath%\\keystore.keystore --ks-pass pass:anonym --ks-key-alias anonym ../APK/%npm_package_name%%npm_package_config_prefix%.%npm_package_version%.apk",
    "apk:release": "npm run apk:build && npm run apk:align && npm run apk:sign",
    "apk:version": "echo %npm_package_version%",
    "apk:testParam": "echo %npm_package_config_keystorepath%"
  },
  "config": {
    "prefix": ".V5",
    "apkpath": ".",
    "keystorepath": "."
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^12.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1200.5",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.3",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/background-geolocation": "^5.37.3",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/camera": "^5.37.3",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/core": "^5.37.3",
    "@awesome-cordova-plugins/geolocation": "^5.37.3",
    "@ionic-native/app-version": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/background-mode": "^5.15.1",
    "@ionic-native/core": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/diagnostic": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/file-path": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-maps": "^5.5.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/insomnia": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/is-debug": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/network": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/sqlite": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "^5.36.0",
    "@ionic/angular": "^5.9.1",
    "@ionic/core": "^5.6.14",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@turf/turf": "^5.1.6",
    "ajv": "6.9.1",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "cordova-android": "~10.1.1",
    "cordova-browser": "6.0.0",
    "cordova-ios": "5.1.1",
    "cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.12",
    "cordova-plugin-background-mode": "^0.7.3",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-file": "^6.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-filepath": "^1.6.0",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-insomnia": "^4.3.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^5.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-is-debug": "^1.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-network-information": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "core-js": "^3.16.4",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "martinez-polygon-clipping": "^0.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.5.3",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "typeorm": "0.2.20",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/dev-server": "^7.3.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular-devkit/build-webpack": "0.1202.3",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.3",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.0",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^4.0.0",
    "@ionic/lab": "^3.2.10",
    "@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation": "^3.1.0",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "12.2.3",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
    "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": "^1.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^6.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.1.0",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps.git#0b8ea76ad34fb2a202a9de1b9d0e051a82ad9443",
    "cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk": "git+https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-sdk.git",
    "cordova-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.10.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^10.0.0",
    "shelljs": "^0.8.4",
    "sql.js": "^1.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5",
    "webpack": "5.50.0",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "5.0.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
    "webpack-subresource-integrity": "1.5.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "@mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation": {
        "GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION": "11+",
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_LIBRARY_VERSION": "26+",
        "ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
        "SMALL_ICON": "@mipmap/icon",
        "ACCOUNT_NAME": "@string/app_name",
        "ACCOUNT_LABEL": "@string/app_name",
        "ACCOUNT_TYPE": "$PACKAGE_NAME.account",
        "CONTENT_AUTHORITY": "$PACKAGE_NAME"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-app-version": {},
      "cordova-plugin-is-debug": {},
      "cordova-sqlite-storage": {},
      "cordova-plugin-file": {},
      "cordova-plugin-background-mode": {},
      "cordova-plugin-network-information": {},
      "cordova-plugin-camera": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_V4_VERSION": "27.+",
        "ANDROIDX_CORE_VERSION": "1.6.+"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": {},
      "cordova-plugin-insomnia": {},
      "cordova-plugin-filepath": {},
      "cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter": {},
      "cordova-plugin-geolocation": {
        "GPS_REQUIRED": "true"
      },
      "cordova-plugin-googlemaps": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "browser",
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it work adding this in my angular.json file into build section :

```
"aot": false,
"vendorChunk": true,
"extractLicenses": false,
"buildOptimizer": false,
"sourceMap": true
```

This solves breakpoints problems but not dettaching, and makes first build (with babel) far longer ...